# Android app not receiving FCM push notification from Python Server (iOS is)

Tags: java, python, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on making an Android version of an iOS app I made earlier this year. 
I have a Python Flask API that is supposed to send a push notification via Firebase Cloud Messaging to Android and iOS devices when a certain endpoint is called.

My iOS app is working perfectly, but on Android I don't receive any notifications (neither in foreground nor background).

In my Python code, I'm using a `MulticastMessage`:

```
push_notification = messaging.MulticastMessage(
    device_tokens,
    notification=messaging.Notification(title=title, body=message),
    data=data,
    apns=messaging.APNSConfig(
        payload=messaging.APNSPayload(
            messaging.Aps(sound="default")
        )
    ),
    android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
        notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(
            sound="default"
        )
    )
)

response = messaging.send_multicast(push_notification)
```

`device_tokens` is a list of the registration tokens of the devices I want to send the notification to. I verified that one of the tokens is, indeed, the token that my Android Client is using.
`data` is a dictionary of the following form:

```
{
    "uid": "<user-uid-here>"
}
```

On the client side, I tried to follow the documentation pretty closely. I added my `google-services.json` file, added and applied the plugin in the Gradle files, and added the Firebase Messaging dependency. Then I created a Messaging Service and updated my app manifest:

#### MessagingService.java

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public MessagingService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.w("Debug", "RECEIVED MESSAGE");
    }
}
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!--Inside application tag-->
<service
    android:name=".model.MessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" /> 
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

I should mention that at some point it was sort of working (sometimes I would get the notification, sometimes I wouldn't), but I can't remember exactly what I did that broke it (if I did do anything at all).

I've Googled in a lot of places, but nothing seems to be working.

Am I missing something? I'm pretty confident the problem is not with the server, since the iOS app is handling the notifications just fine.

NOTE: I want to be able to receive messages from both foreground and background state.

EDIT: I am running this on an emulator; perhaps that might be related to the problem? I remember sometimes before the device wouldn't get the notification for a long time...

Comment: Have you tried checking the priority levels of the notifications you're sending? Especially on Android, those can determine if the notification is shown to the user or not

Comment: I didn't create a notification channel. Do I need to do that? (I saw something about that on Android 8 and above; I'm testing on Android 9 I believe)

Comment: Yep, notification channels are required at Android 8 and above

Comment: But that won't affect if ```onMessageReceived``` isn't firing. If the receiver doesn't ever  print that log message, then the issue is with your firebase code that sends the function, not the android notification code.

Comment: I created a notification channel, and it started working. It still experiences weird delays sometimes, but overall it's working much better.

Comment: Good stuff! I will agree emulators could be part of the delay, I have trouble with those myself sometimes.